# how do I delete a regex-delimited range plus a few lines with sed?

Tags: sed

I have a file containing a header I want to get rid of.  I don't have a good way of addressing either the last line of the header or the first line of the data, but I can address the line before the next-to-last line of the header via a regular expression.

Example input:

```
a bunch of make output which I don't care about
for junk in blah; do
    can't check for done!
done
for test in blurfl; do # this is the addressable line
    more garbage
done
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
```

I've done the obvious `1,/for test in blurfl/d`, but that doesn't get the next two lines.  I can make the command `{N;d}` which gets rid of the next line, but `{N;N;d}` just blows away the rest of the file except the last line, which I figured out is because the range isn't slurped up and treated as a single entity, but instead is processed line-by-line.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious because I don't know some sed idiom, but none of the examples on the web or in the GNU manual have managed to trigger anything useful.

I can do this in awk, but other transformations I need to do make awk somewhat, well, awkward.  But GNU sed is acceptable.

Comment: A different approach would be to get the number of the last line to be removed by using `grep -n` and then use `sed` to remove the lines up to that one you've got.

Comment: How did you get on with the advice below, Danek?

Comment: I dug up the changeset which seems to be what I was working on, and it looks like I used `1,/^for test in/{N;d}`. I can't tell for sure how I worked around its deficiency, though I think I ended up just ignoring the line it didn't delete, and that was okay.

Fundamentally, I agree with `sed` maybe not being the best tool here; it's just that the framework I was working with used `sed` as the default filtering program, and switching that out would have been more work, in addition to the `awk` program being way more bulky than I wanted (to fit into a couple lines in a Makefile).

Answer (score 2):

I have to disagree about [not] using `awk`.  Anything non-trivial is almost always easier in `awk` than `sed` [even the `sed` manpage says so].  Personally, I'd use `perl`, but ...

So, here's the `awk` script:

```
BEGIN {
    phase = 0
}

# initial match -- find second loop
phase == 0 {
    if ($0 ~ /for test in blurfl/) {
        phase = 1
        next
    }
}

# wait for end of second loop
phase == 1 {
    if ($0 ~ /done/) {
        phase = 2
        next
    }
}

# print phase
phase == 2 {
    print($0)
}
```

If you wish to torture yourself [and `sed`] for complex changes, well, caveat emptor, but don't say I didn't warn you ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do multi line matches in sed. First time I went down this rabbit hole I ended up using awk, which can support, but now recently I'd probably use Python or Ruby for this kind of thing.